# Game like Team Buddies but open-source?

Tags: games

Im looking for a game like [Team Buddies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Buddies) ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7vXE-BeWSM)), with online multiplayer mode for ubuntu.. possibly open-source.

Anyone know something similar?

Comment: Well, this is a really original gameplay, I don't think someone will find a totally similar game. But if you tell us what you like in the gameplay of this game, I think we might 
be able to find games with the same aspects.

Comment: @Nyamiou: i like everythings of it! It's the perfect mix of strategy and arcade. I love the ability to create weapons, other buddies or vehicles, the 3D... By now, on ubuntu i play Teeworlds, this could be a great sobstitute, if only has a little bit of strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this site http://www.ubuntugamer.com/

This site is dedicated for gaming in ubuntu. You can find lot of games at this site. 
I hope you can find some interesting games from this site.Just try and what ever the result feel free to post it here.

Comment: I found many intersting games, but noone like team buddies ;(

Comment: Ubuntu Gamer is no more available because it was merged on main site OMG Ubuntu http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/
Others Linux Game interesting site are Penguspy http://www.penguspy.com and Desura http://www.desura.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's not online but you could buy a few controllers and use this:

http://psxemulator.gazaxian.com/

Comment: Nhà, im not tring to emulate Team Buddies with a playstation emulator.. im looking for a open-source games similar to it ;)